# Assistance with Rock, Paper, Scissor game

Tags: java

I am very new to this. I have just started taking programming classes at college (CS 107 and CS 108 intro to java). My homework was to create a Rock, Paper Scissor game between computer and user. I was getting the error message on java that on my compPlay string has not been declared. It has already been fixed thanks to @caps lock. Now, after I run the program it does print the instructions but once I enter the input (0,1 or 2) it does not tell me if it's a tie, if I won or lost. Can anyone spot where I messed up? Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.Random;

public class Lab3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
{
        String userPlay; // 0=Scissor, 1=Rock, 2=Paper
        String compPlay = ""; // 0=Scissor, 1=Rock, 2=Paper
        int compInt; // Random generated number from 0-2

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random generator = new Random();
        System.out.print("Let's play Rock, Paper, Scissor! Please enter 0 for Scissor, 1 for Rock or 2 for Paper.  ");
        System.out.println();

        // Random generated number from 0-2
        compInt = (int)(Math.random())*3;


    // Translate computer random number selected into string

    if (compInt == (0))
{
    compPlay = "Scissor";
}
    else if (compInt == (1))
{
    compPlay = "Rock";
}
    else if (compInt == (2))
{
    compPlay = "Paper";
}

    // Get user input
    System.out.println("Enter your choice ");
    userPlay = scan.next();

    // Print computer random number
    System.out.println("Computer is: " + compInt);

    // Set who wins, loses or ties

    if(userPlay.equals (compInt))
{
    System.out.println("It's a tie!");
}
    else if (userPlay.equals (1))
{
    if (compPlay.equals("0"))
    System.out.println("Computer is Scissor. You are Rock. You win!");
    else if (compPlay.equals("2"))
    System.out.println("Computer is Paper. You are Rock. You lose.");
}

    else if (userPlay.equals(2))
{
    if (compPlay.equals("Scissor"))
    System.out.println("Computer is Scissor. You are Paper. You lose.");
    else if (compPlay.equals("Rock"))
    System.out.println("Computer is Rock. You are Paper. You win!");
}
    else if (userPlay.equals(0))
{
    if (compPlay.equals("Rock"))
    System.out.println("Computer is Rock. You are Scissor. You lose.");
    else if (compPlay.equals("Paper"))
    System.out.println("computer is Paper. You are Scissor. You win!");
}

}// main
}// class
```

Comment: A `String` is never equal to an `Integer` (an `int`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compile you need to initialize first ..

```
String compPlay = "";
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much! It got rid of the error messages. I was able to run it.. but when I enter the input it's not saying whether I lost, won or tied. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `.equals()` with a string to compare with an int. What I recommend doing is changing the type of userPlay to an int and make the following changes. First line after main:

```
int userPlay;
```

Now change `userPlay = scan.next();` to:

```
userPlay = scan.nextInt();
```

And when comparing userPlay, change the several if statements to:

```
if(userPlay == compInt)
if(userPlay == 0)
if(userPlay == 2)
... etc
```

I think you don't need strings at all here, because you are entering simple numbers, not words like *scissors*. You can take this code over to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and they can help you improve it! I recommend also practicing more comparisons between data types! Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

You're a student, so you can be forgiven for writing a wall of code in a main method, but here's something to consider when you're farther along in your programming education:

Java's an object oriented language.  Start trying to think in terms of behavior encapsulated in objects, like this:

Choices:

```
package game.rps;

/**
 * Choices for rock paper scissors
 * @author Michael
 * @link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310090/assistance-with-rock-paper-scissor-game
 * @since 10/10/2014 9:42 PM
 */
public enum Choice {
    ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS
}
```

Outcomes:

```
package game.rps;

/**
 * Outcome for rock paper scissors
 * @author Michael
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310090/assistance-with-rock-paper-scissor-game
 * @since 10/10/2014 9:44 PM
 */
public enum Outcome {
    LOSE, DRAW, WIN
}
```

Player represents the computer:

```
package game.rps;

import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Player represents the computer in the game
 * @author Michael
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310090/assistance-with-rock-paper-scissor-game
 * @since 10/10/2014 9:54 PM
 */
public class Player {

    private Random random;

    public Player() {
        this.random = new Random();
    }

    public Player(long seed) {
        this.random = new Random(seed);
    }

    public Choice decide() {
        int index = this.random.nextInt(Choice.values().length);
        return Choice.values()[index];
    }
}
```

Driver for playing the game:

```
package game.rps;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Game loop for playing rock paper scissors
 * @author Michael
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310090/assistance-with-rock-paper-scissor-game
 * @since 10/10/2014 9:43 PM
 */
public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Game game = new Game();
        Player player = new Player();
        do {
            System.out.println("ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS, or QUIT: ");
            input = in.nextLine().trim();
            Choice human = Choice.valueOf(input);
            Choice computer = player.decide();
            System.out.println(String.format("computer: %s", computer));
            System.out.println(String.format("human   : %s", human));
            System.out.println(String.format("outcome : %s", game.play(human, computer)));
        } while (!"QUIT".equalsIgnoreCase(input));
    }

    public  Outcome play(Choice player1, Choice player2) {
        if (player1 == player2) {
            return Outcome.DRAW;
        } else {
            if (player1 == Choice.ROCK) {
                return (player2 == Choice.PAPER ? Outcome.LOSE : Outcome.WIN);
            } else if (player1 == Choice.PAPER) {
                return (player2 == Choice.SCISSORS ? Outcome.LOSE : Outcome.WIN);
            } else {
                return (player2 == Choice.ROCK ? Outcome.LOSE : Outcome.WIN);
            }
        }
    }
}
```